# Leaflet SVG layer is obscuring the underlying GeoJSON interactivity

Tags: leaflet, geojson, svg

I have SVG on top of GeoJSON in my map. How can a leaflet SVG overlay be placed outside of the leaflet-overlay-pane while keeping GeoJSON in-place within the leaflet-overlay-pane? (For example, how could I put just the SVG into say the leaflet-shadow-pane and then turn pointer events off on the leaflet-shadow-pane  making it possible to interact with the GeoJSON?)

Thus-far, when I set:

```
.leaflet-overlay-pane svg {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

it seems to disable to disable pointer events to both the SVG and GeoJSON, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: I think the problem is that two svg roots are created: one by GeoJSON and one by your own SVG. The last one added to the map "wins". Can you add the code in which you load the SVG to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Add the SVG to `map.getPanes().shadowPane`.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn off interactivity of a svg with `interactivity: false`

Comment: A good answer should include details about how and where to use your solution, and what it does to solve the problem.  Please [edit] your answer to expand with more detailed explanation.